# App with no DB: You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class

Tags: facebook, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, durandal

First things first. I'm a complete OAuth newbie. This will be my first stab at it, and things are getting hairy...

I'm writing a single page application using Durandal & Web API.
The user needs to be able to login using any social network.
I don't have access to a database whatsoever, I have to call an unprotected 3rd party web service which I consume server-side, and need to protect using OAuth.

So I've managed to add the files to my solution which generates the login using facebook contol/button (created a new MVC4 web application, and did a manual copy and paste of all the auth related files, updated bootstrappers etc..), and the code seems to work for the most part.

When facebook redirects back to

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
 {
     AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(this.Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
     if (!result.IsSuccessful)
     {
        return this.RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
     }

     if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
     {
        return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
     }

        //code removed for brevity       ....
  }
```

I get the error specified once the following line tries to execute.

> OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false)

I've removed the [InitializeSimpleMembership] attribute from the controller, as I don't have a database.

Please forgive me if this is the dumbest question ever, but...

Why does the login fail? I mean at that point, isn't the app trying to log into facebook, why does it need a databse? Or am I correct in saying I can remove/replace that code section, with a login/authorise call on the web-service I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the dumbest question ever. [Not by a long shot](http://www.sofunnyomg.com/dumbest-question-ever/). But you are getting the error because your membership provider is still set to use the `SimpleMembershipProvider` and `OAuthWebSecurity` will use the default membership provider. If you don't want to use a database you will have to create or find a different membership provider to use.

EDIT:
I know you said you don't have access to a DB but if you can use SQL Compact you can just stick with the default SimpleMembershipProvider(check out Hanselman's [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)) or DevArt has a [SQLLite provider](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/articles/extendedmembership-tutorial.html). Also the [MemFlex Project](https://github.com/OdeToCode/Memflex) has a RavenDb provider. If none of those work I think you might just have to write your own.

Comment: hahaha.... +1 for the link. Any alternative membership providers that you're aware of that i can use?